# Completely destroy docker container

Tags: docker

I borked my Wordpress docker container. I want to destroy it and all the information within, and start fresh. I run `docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm` then I hit it with a `docker system prune -a` for good measure. Now I rebuild and restart the container `docker-compose up -d —build` and it is in the same sorry broken state. How do I completely destroy the container?

Comment: Are you running the standard Wordpress image or a custom image? If you're running a custom image, you need to delete the image using `docker image rm <image tag>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker-compose down --volumes --rmi all --remove-orphans
```

This command also cleans up all orphaned containers associated with your Docker Compose project. Remember to use this command carefully, especially the `--volumes` and `--rmi` all options, as they will delete data and images.